# How to call a method every time an activity is being viewed?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

How to call a method every time an activity is being viewed?

For an example, I navigate from `activity1` to `activity2`. Now I again navigate to `activity1`. Each and every time the `activity1` is being displayed/navigated to that activity, I need to run the method `loadEveryTime()`. How can I do this? Please help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`onResume()` is called every time the Activity is resumed, so put your method call in there. Make sure to call up to the superclass.

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
  super.onResume();
  loadEveryTime();
}
```